# Using data.table::fread in R to read in date column with non-ISO format

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a file that I am reading in.  Everything is fine, except for one detail.  In the file, dates are stored in the format "mm/dd/yyyy".  When I try to read this in with fread, I'm using

```
fread(..., select = c(var = "Date"))
```

It appears fread assumes it's in the ISO format, so January 9, 2019 stored as 1/9/2019 is read in as the date"0001-09-20", September 20, year 1.  Is there any way to specify a format to tell fread how to read this?  It could be in select or colClasses, though select is my preference as I've already selected around 80 columns and specified their data types.

I know I could read it in as character and change it afterward.  I'm trying to do as much as possible while reading in the data.  If I have to change it after the fact, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Read as character and convert in extra step.
2. Fill feature request in data.table github repo providing your minimal example file and wait for it to be implemented.

Personally I would go with the first one. Good thing is that you can do both.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer I was looking for!